# Preventing a user from adding unwanted data in a map within a document in Firebase Firestore using Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a document (myLists) within a collection within a users personal area on Firebase Firestore:

.../users/{userID}/data/myLists

Which is used to keep minimal information about all the different lists a user has is map form, so there are multiple maps with a unique id as the key and then a field with the key 'title' and the value a string (I've have illustrated as key:value pairs below):

```
[
    'bb28fd2a-1001-475f-be58-6da84054a274': ['title': 'My fav list'],
    'd615136b-ebaf-4ba3-8b69-287320e801fd': ['title': 'My second fav list']
]
```

This is where I have the client write to, with just a title and a UUID, in order to create their new list and I then use a cloud function to create a new document in my top level 'lists' collection.

I want to prevent the user from writing any thing else to the database other than the listID and the title of their list (as illustrated above) but I'm struggling as it is a technically a map within a map.

I know that a way of doing this if I just had single fields in my document could be:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['title']);
```

But because I'm adding a new map to the document each time a new list is created and that the key of the map is a random unique ID, I'm not sure how to do it.

I know that I can use the 'diff' method to see the changes between the request and resource when updating and that may be a way of obtaining the random map key, as I'm only ever going to be adding one map at a time, but not sure how to implement it.

Any help will be appreciated or if this is really not the way to go about it, please let me know:)

Comment: Consider using a whole new document in another nested subcollection for each entry, instead of adding them all to the same document.  Not only does this scale better, but you will have an easy time with the rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your reply! I'll give that a try:)